# Import .csv to .xls workbook (not just one sheet) using VB macro

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am new to VBA & macros in Excel and thus have a question.

I have an Excel workbook, with one main sheet called "BASE". Here there is one column where values are filled. There are two types of these values:

1. Scalar value and can be entered directly in this sheet only.
2. Array of values. So, there is a hyperlink to other sheet in the workbook where such an array of values are to be filled. 
   I have a .csv file containing these values and I have to fill values in .xls file using a VBA macro. Can anyone tell how to do that?

Consider the main.xls as having 4 inputs with 2 as scalar and 2 as array (and thus, linking to the other sheets of the workbook). So, when .csv file is read, single values are inserted on the BASE sheet and two tables are filled (for the array input from .csv file) using the hyperlink on BASE sheet for these sheets, in the same Workbook.

Comment: What is the best way to learn [VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901783/1490783)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below will parse data (only if delimited by semicolons - you will have to change what is set to 'true' for your data):

```
Sub Parse_Setup()

DoEvents

Application.StatusBar = "Parsing Data"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = "" Then 'this makes sure the destination cells are empty
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
        )), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Something like this will select a file:

```
Sub SelectFile()

Dim Fname As String

Application.StatusBar = "Getting FileName from User"
ActiveSheet.Range("C3") = ""

Dim iFileSelect As FileDialog
Set iFileSelect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
    If iFileSelect.Show = -1 Then
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In iFileSelect.SelectedItems
            MsgBox "The path is: " & vrtSelectedItem
            Range("C3") = vrtSelectedItem
        Next vrtSelectedItem
    End If
Set iFileSelect = Nothing

Fname = Range("C3")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:=Fname

Application.StatusBar = "File Opened"

End Sub
```

I would suggest you use something like this and then setup your data from there however you need to. Feel free to update your question. The part where you say what sheets certain data goes to didn't make much sense, at least no in the abstract. Post up some code!